# Doxygen comments with undeclared functions in C++ headers

Tags: c++, header, doxygen

I've got a code with member functions defined in the .cpp file that are not declared in the .h file. Contrary to what I would expect, it compiles without any problem.

I want to generate some documentation with Doxygen but the comments I add before the member functions that are undeclared in the header file don't seem to be recognized by Doxygen.

Is there any workaround to this problem, other than defining the functions in the header file?

Comment: I would stay away from the compiler :) Maybe there are multiple headers for the class ????

Comment: Yes, it certainly is contrary to expectation that this could compile...

Comment: @user1541379 Are you sure, that you configured Doxygen to read both, the implementation files and the headers?

Comment: I doubt that you can define a member function for which there is no declaration (we are talking about classes here, right?). Can you provide a code snippet for this?

Answer (score 0):

> I've got a code with member functions defined in the .cpp file that are not declared in the .h file. Contrary to what I would expect, it compiles without any problem.

Do you mean this?

```
// Foo.h
class Foo
{
  void bar ();
  // no method "meh".
};

// Foo.cpp
int Foo::meh (const std::string& message)
{
   // ...
};
```

Because that shouldn't compile.

If you mean this:

```
// Foo.h
void bar ();
// no function "meh".

// Foo.cpp
int meh (const std::string& message)
{
   // ...
}
```

Then that's perfectly OK (free functions don't require a declaration in a header file).

---

> I want to generate some documentation with Doxygen but the comments I add before the member functions that are undeclared in the header file don't seem to be recognized by Doxygen.

This depends on your Doxygen configuration.  Make sure you set the INPUT_PATTERNS setting to include both source files and header files.  Also make sure that free-standing function commands explicitly refer to some symbol (e.g. use the `@fn meh` command to document a `meh` function).