# Use doxygen to document an undeclared function in a C++-like language

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I am working on a proprietary tool which uses a C++-like language to define various methods. The tool provides its own compiler to compile these methods into a .so file. It does not follow the "declaration-definition" syntax of C++, but is otherwise quite similar. An example code looks like the following:

```
method _foo::bar(var message) {
    // do something with 'message' here
}
```

I tried documenting this method using doxygen as follows:

```
/**
  * @brief this method does something with @a message.
  */
method _foo::bar(var message) {
    // do something with 'message' here
}
```

but this gave me a warning:

```
warning: documented function `method _foo::bar' was not declared or defined.
```

I tried with adding `@fn method _foo::bar()`, `@fn _foo::bar`, and `@fn bar` to the comment block (one by one), but neither of them resulted in the `@brief` message being added to the document.

I have searched here on Stack Overflow, and this post [Doxygen comments with undeclared functions in C++ headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583920/doxygen-comments-with-undeclared-functions-in-c-headers) is the closest to my question, but it doesn't quite address my problem.

Is there any way to configure doxygen to generate documentation for a function regardless of the fact that it is undeclared?

Comment: How much is the Doxygen preprocessor seeing at all in your code?  If you set `EXTRACT_ALL` to `YES` do you get any sort of outline of your code? If not, then you may need a custom preprocessor for this language.